# Starting to version an already medium size project

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am about to start participating in the development of a medium-sized project (~50k lines) that was until now written by a single person, and not versioned; as a result folders are cluttered with different versions of the same file (named file1, file2, file3, etc.).

I proposed to start using a VCS for it (a priori Mercurial, which is the only one I've ever used -- for my personal projects --, but I'm open to suggestions), so I'm taking any good ideas as to how to "start" the repository.  E.g., should I make an initial commit with all the existing files, and immediately make a new commit with the unused files removed?  Or something else?

(constructive remarks on mercurial vs bazaar vs git vs whatever are also welcome.)

Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 4):

> E.g., should I make an initial commit with all the existing files, and immediately make a new commit with the unused files removed?

If the size of the repository is not a concern, then yes, that is a good starting point. Otherwise you can just commit what's actually used, and go from there.

As for which system, all DVCSes stick to the same core principles. Which one you pick is entirely subjective — the only way to truly know which one you like is to try each one.

Answer (score 1):

I would say use what you are the most comfortable with and meets your needs.  As far as where to start, I personally would seed the repo with the current source as is, that way you can verify that everything builds and runs as expected.  you can make this initial seed a branch.  That way you can always go back to your starting point before refactoring.

Comment: Why making it a branch? You can go back to anything that state that has a revision.

Comment: You can, just depends on what you want to do.  Can be done on trunk ( sorry , SVN is my main CM ) and then just refactored in place, or if you are removing and/or moving alot of code, you may just want to have the branch for a reference.  Personal preference...

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this was:

1. create a Mercurial repository in the existing project folder ("existing")
2. commit all project files to "existing"
3. create an empty repository in what a different location ("new")
4. As files are tested and QA'd (this was necessary because there was so much dross in "existing") pull them from "everything" to "new".
5. Once files had been pulled into "new"; delete the corresponding files from "existing". If access is needed to these files while the migration is under way, push them back from "new" to "existing".

This gave me the advantage of putting everything under some sort of control for recovery purposes, control over introducing the project to the DVCS. Eventually the existing project folder became completely tested and approved for the project moving forward. At this point the "everything" directory could be deleted or changed into a working folder; and "new" became the actual project folder.

Comment: @Oben I don't know whether you're pulling my leg or not (my humour detector isn't very sensitive). If you are I can only say that I always seem to dream up solutions that are correct but way too complicated initially - and then simplify, simplify, simplify. If not I would add my justification that the project I had to put into version control had so many duplicate files; false starts; and general mess in the existing project, that the only way to ensure it was on a firm footing moving forward was to test and QA every file that was "admitted" to the continuing development.

Comment: . either. It looks quite complex, I didn't get it on the first read, so a more verbose/structured description might be helpful. On the other side I was wondering why all these steps are necessary at all (compared to @Cat's answer). Anyway, please don't take it too seriously.

Comment: @Oben - I agree @Cat's answer is clearer and better. I am editing my answer to make it a little clearer. As for taking it seriously - I'm thinking of having "KISS" tattooed on my forehead in mirror writing, so when I look in a mirror ......

Comment: too bad you removed the "introduce the DVCS to the project", I liked the joke :p

Answer (score 1):

I think Mercurial is a good choice. Lightweight, fast, very simple to use and well-integrated with Windows (if that's the platform you're dealing with).

I would probably get rid of all the clutter *before* the first commit. Delete everything you don't care about, run all the necessary tests and only then do the commit.

Yes, I'm dead set against the 0-day cluttering of repos.

Granted, a 50K SLOC project isn't very big, but if you commit files you already know you won't need, they will make your repo slightly bigger.

Also, remember to check that the tree doesn't contain large binary files. If it does, get rid of them if at all possible.